# Datatable not displaying search box and not allowing sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have the following html code for table:

```
<table id="employeeDetails" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Team</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

And the following code for dataTable initialization:

```
$('#employeeDetailsTable').dataTable({
        "processing":true,
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : '/fetchSearchResults',
            "type" : 'POST'
            }
        }
});
```

I read in many places on the internet that sorting feature and search box in datatable is not provided if colspan is used. Even after not using colspan I'm not getting these features in my datatable. What can be the possible reason for this?

Comment: How does the result from fetchSearchResults looks like?

Comment: You have a `}` curly brace too many in `dataTable()` ....

Comment: @davidkonrad My code does not have that extra "}". That was a typo. When I add "searching":true to the dataTable, a search box appears, but when I actually try to search something, the dataTable isn't able to do the search.